# Where does the pH come from in the equation of Standard Hydrogen Electrode?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

$$\mathrm{E=-{2.303RT \over F}pH - {RT \over 2F}\ln {p_{H_2}/p^0}}$$
This is a equation on Wikipedia page of Standard Hydrogen Electrode, but I have no idea where the $pH$ come from.
Since $\mathrm{a_{H^+}=f_{H^+} C_{H^+} /C_0}$, how does the $\mathrm{f_{H^+}}$ disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few logarithm rules that you need to apply here.
\begin{align}
E &= \mathrm{RT \over F}\ln {a_{H^+} \over (p_{H_2}/p^0)^{1/2}}\\
  &= \mathrm{RT \over F}\ln a_{H^+} - \mathrm{RT \over F} \ln \left({p_{H_2} \over p^0}\right)^{1/2}\\
  &= \mathrm{\ln(10) RT \over F} \lg a_{H^+} - {1 \over 2}\mathrm{RT \over F}\ln \left({p_{H_2} \over p^0}\right)\\
  &= -\mathrm{2.303 RT \over F} \mathrm{pH} - {1 \over 2}\mathrm{RT \over F}\ln \left({p_{H_2} \over p^0}\right)
\end{align}

---

You need a few logarithm rules:

- $\log\left({a \over b}\right) = \log(a) - \log(b)$
- $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log_a(x)}{\log_a(b)}$
- $\log_b(x^r) = r \log_b(x)$

Comment: I tried editing but there's a 6 character minimum. You've got a small typo in the derivation. Next to last line from bottom, lg(CH+) should be log(CH+)

Comment: I simply don't understand why $f_{H^+} \approx 1$, since the concentration we are dealing is not low.

Comment: You don't need $f_{\ce{H+}} \approx 1$, because the definition of $\mathrm{pH}$ is not $\mathrm{pH} = - \log (c_{\ce{H+}})$ but rather  $\mathrm{pH} = - \log (a_{\ce{H+}})$. The definition based on the concentration is just an often used approximation which assumes $f_{\ce{H+}} \approx 1$ and is only valid in cases where this assumption is valid.

Comment: @SeanDoris: Thank you, but this is correct. ["...  $\log_{10}(x)$ should be written $\lg (x)$ and $\log_e(x)$ should be $\ln (x)$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm), so it is correct.

Comment: @Philipp: Thank you, you are right ... changed it.

Comment: @pH13 Fair enough. I haven't seen that convention (and I personally don't care for it now that I have seen it), but by all means keep using it if you think it's clearer